# python replace regex for dynamic string

Tags: python, regex

In Wikipedia pages are expressions like:

> [[File Transfer Protocol|FTP server]]
> [[server (computing)|server]]

I can remove it by

```
pattern = '\[\[.*\|.*\]\]'
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
```

But I want replace it by second part after pipe char.

> FTP server
> server

or

> [[FTP server]]
> [[server]]

This is possible by regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
import re

s = '[[File Transfer Protocol|FTP server]] [[server (computing)|server]]'

print(re.sub(r'[^\]\[\|]+\|([^\]\[\|]+)', r'\1', s))
```

Prints:

```
[[FTP server]] [[server]]
```

---

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/JbtfUa/1)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that just removing the first part between the opening bracket and pipe ?

```
import re

s = '[[File Transfer Protocol|FTP server]] [[server (computing)|server]]'

r = re.sub(r"[^\]\[]*?\|","",s)

print(r)

[[FTP server]] [[server]]
```

or you could extract and join the second parts:

```
r = " ".join(re.findall(r"(?<=\|).+?(?=\])",s))

print(r)

FTP server server
```

Answer (score 1):

If there can not be any `[` or `]` chars in between, you can match the format `[[...]]` and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) in between to exclude the characters that are not allowed.

Then use a capture group to capture what you want to keep, and use group 1 in the replacement.

```
\[\[[^][|]*\|([^][]*)]]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q7R7NK/1)

```
import re

pattern = r'\[\[[^][|]*\|([^][]*)]]'
text = '[[File Transfer Protocol|FTP server]] [[server (computing)|server]]'

print(re.sub(pattern, r'\1', text))
```

Output

```
FTP server server
```

---

If there can be `[` or `]` chars in between and there always is a pip present, you could use a non greedy dot `.*?` instead and also use a capture group:

```
\[\[[^|]*\|(.*?)]]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2VBDD/1)